# I'm legally divorced from my husband; how can I get talaq from him?

Tags: talaq, husband-wife

I legally divorced my husband, we're not living together for over a year. I don't love him or find him attractive anymore. I want to move on.  How can I get talaq from him? Is there any way possible?

Comment: There is an option. That name is kulah.  Wife can give the divorce to husband.

Comment: You can ask him or go to a court and ask for khul'a or maybe they would check if faskh could be an option based on the fact that your husband doesn't fulfil his dueties. In case of khul'a you must "buy yiurself free".

Comment: what do you mean by legally divorced ? Does your husband said that I gave to Talaq ?